# What are the rules around whitespace in attribute selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm reading the spec on [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), but I can't find anything that says if whitespace is allowed. I'm guessing it's allowed at the beginning, before and after the operator, and at the end. Is this correct?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The rules on whitespace in attribute selectors are stated in the grammar. Here's the [Selectors 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#w3cselgrammar) production for attribute selectors (some tokens substituted with their string equivalents for illustration; `S*` represents 0 or more whitespace characters):

```
attrib
  : '[' S* [ namespace_prefix ]? IDENT S*
        [ [ '^=' |
            '$=' |
            '*=' |
            '=' |
            '~=' |
            '|=' ] S* [ IDENT | STRING ] S*
        ]? ']'
  ;
```

Of course, the grammar isn't terribly useful to someone looking to understand how to *write* attribute selectors, as it's intended for someone who's *implementing* a selector engine.

Here's a plain-English explanation:

#### Whitespace before the attribute selector

This isn't covered in the above production, but the first obvious rule is that if you're attaching an attribute selector to another simple selector or a pseudo-element, **don't** use a space:

```
a[href]::after
```

If you do, the space is treated as a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators) instead, with the universal selector implied on the attribute selector and anything that may follow it. In other words, these selectors are equivalent to each other, but different from the above:

```
a [href] ::after
a *[href] *::after
```

#### Whitespace inside the attribute selector

Whether you have any whitespace within the brackets and around the comparison operator doesn't matter; I find that browsers seem to treat them as if they weren't there (but I haven't tested extensively). These are all valid according to the grammar and, as far as I've seen, work in all *modern* browsers:

```
a[href]
a[ href ]
a[ href="http://stackoverflow.com" ]
a[href ^= "http://"]
a[ href ^= "http://" ]
```

Whitespace is not allowed between the `^` (or other symbol) and `=` as these are treated as a single token, and tokens cannot be broken apart.

If IE7 and IE8 implement the grammar correctly, they should be able to handle them all as well.

If a [namespace prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attrnmsp) is used, whitespace is not allowed between the prefix and the attribute name.

These are incorrect:

```
unit[sh| quantity]
unit[ sh| quantity="200" ]
unit[sh| quantity = "200"]
```

These are correct:

```
unit[sh|quantity]
unit[ sh|quantity="200" ]
unit[sh|quantity = "200"]
```

#### Whitespace within the attribute value

But notice the quotes around the attribute values above; if you leave them out, and you try to select something whose attribute has spaces in its value you have a syntax error.

This is incorrect:

```
div[class=one two]
```

This is correct:

```
div[class="one two"]
```

This is because an unquoted attribute value is treated as an identifier, which doesn't include whitespace (for obvious reasons), whereas a quoted value is treated as a string. See [this spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) for more details.

To prevent such errors, I strongly recommend always quoting attribute values, whether in HTML, XHTML (required), XML (required), CSS or jQuery ([once required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987068/do-you-use-quotes-in-jquery-when-searching-for-attribute-values/9987074#9987074)).

#### Whitespace after the attribute value

As of Selectors 4 (following the original publication of this answer), attribute selectors can accept flags in the form of an identifier appearing after the attribute value. Two flags have been defined pertaining to [character case](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-case), one for case-insensitive matching:

```
div[data-foo="bar" i]
```

And one for case-sensitive matching (whose addition [I had a part in](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4158), albeit by proxy of the WHATWG):

```
ol[type="A" s]
ol[type="a" s]
```

The grammar has been [updated](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#grammar) thus:

```
attrib
  : '[' S* attrib_name ']'
    | '[' S* attrib_name attrib_match [ IDENT | STRING ] S* attrib_flags? ']'
  ;

attrib_name
  : wqname_prefix? IDENT S*

attrib_match
  : [ '=' |
      PREFIX-MATCH |
      SUFFIX-MATCH |
      SUBSTRING-MATCH |
      INCLUDE-MATCH |
      DASH-MATCH
    ] S*

attrib_flags
  : IDENT S*
```

In plain English: if the attribute value is not quoted (i.e. it is an identifier), whitespace between it and `attrib_flags` is required; otherwise, if the attribute value is quoted then whitespace is optional, but strongly recommended for the sake of readability. Whitespace between `attrib_flags` and the closing bracket is optional as always.

Comment: I meant strictly within the brackets. i.e., are these all the same? `[a=b]` `[a = b]` `[ a = b ]`

Comment: @Mark: I've expanded my answer quite a bit now.

Comment: The CSS3 spec says "Attribute values must be CSS identifiers or strings.". Identifiers cannot contain spaces, so there's no problems there. I'm more interested in what the spec dictates than what browsers support, but this is helpful nevertheless.

Comment: Heh, the identifiers vs strings thing keeps slipping my mind (it's 7:08 am...) :)

Comment: @Mark: I've updated my answer to include the grammar and incorporated your comment regarding identifiers vs strings.

Comment: Firefox 57 seems to run into issues with added whitespace in a selector like `select:not( [ no-ie ] ) {}`. It ignores the rule completely. Would need more test cases.

Comment: @Volker E.: Ugh, confound it. As if dropping XUL extensions wasn't enough of a reason for me to refuse to upgrade...