# What does the selector [class^="span"] do?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I can't work out what this is:

Line 33 of http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-1.2.0.min.css

```
.row [class^="span"] {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I understand the style but I've never seen this before

```
[class^="span"]
```

Comment: @Gupta: That's not a correct edit. You're literally editing the answer into the title. Besides, I use all those terms in my answer, so the edit isn't even necessary.

Answer (score 86):

This means a class beginning with the word "span", such as:

```
<div class="spanning"></div>
```

The `^` symbol is taken from regular expressions, wherein this symbol refers to the beginning of a string.

It should be noted that this checks for the beginning of the class attribute, not the beginning of the classname.  Which means it will not match said selector:

```
<div class="globe spanning"></div>
```

The above element has two classes, the second of which begins with "span" - but since the attribute `class` begins with "globe", not with "span", it will not match.

One could use `[class*=span]`, which would return all classes containing span, but that would also return other classes, such as `wingspan`.

AFAIK, the way to get classes that begin with a string are to use a double selector:

```
.row [class^="span"], .row [class*=" span"]{}
```

This will return the class beginning with span, whether at the beginning of the attribute, or in the middle.

(I also recall working in a solution in the homegrown selector engines used by [DOMParser](https://github.com/siteroller/domparser)).

Answer (score 37):

That is an attribute selector, specifically one of the [CSS3 substring-matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).

This rule applies styles to any element whose `class` attribute begins with `span` (`^=` means "starts with"), that occurs in any element with the class `row`.

Comment: Remember that the space in between is significant; it's the descendant selector, so `.row [class^="span"]` is not the same as `.row[class^="span"]`.

Comment: More on whitespace around attribute selectors can be found in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930898/what-are-the-rules-around-whitespace-in-attribute-selectors/5930921#5930921).

Answer (score 4):

That is a CSS attribute Selector.

Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/ (Section 2)

> E[foo^="bar"]  an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly
>   with the string "bar"

Comment: Every time I've try to figure something out from reading http://www.w3.org, I've always fallen asleep. 

Thanks for your replies... I kinda get it now