# What is this CSS selector? [class*="span"]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I saw this selector in Twitter Bootstrap:

```
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Does anyone know what this technique is called and what it does?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: Many cool CSS selectors available: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Comment: http://jsbin.com/otizoz/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: Similar but not a complete duplicate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366323/what-does-the-selector-class-span-do (which links back here)

Answer (score 388, accepted):

It's an attribute wildcard selector. In the sample you've given, it looks for any child element under `.show-grid` that has a class that CONTAINS `span`.

So would select the `<strong>` element in this example:

```
<div class="show-grid">
    <strong class="span6">Blah blah</strong>
</div>
```

You can also do searches for 'begins with...'

```
div[class^="something"] { }
```

which would work on something like this:-

```
<div class="something-else-class"></div>
```

and 'ends with...'

```
div[class$="something"] { }
```

which would work on

```
<div class="you-are-something"></div>
```

**Good references**

- [CSS3 Attribute Selectors: Substring Matching](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)
- [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)
- [W3C CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: I know this is old answer but I would add this reference to reference list:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Would like to add another reference just in case people find this useful: http://AllCssSelectors.com

Comment: The `div[class^="something"] { }` "starts with" selector only works if the element contains one single class, or if multiple, when that class is the first one on the left.

Comment: I would add `div[class~="something"]` for finding matches in space separated lists (e.g. classes) and `div[class|="something"` for matching on a hyphen separated list e.g. matching something in you-are-something classname above

Comment: @user3339411 The website is offline so I'm posting an archived version. https://archive.is/FOUHa

Answer (score 34):

```
.show-grid [class*="span"]
```

It's a CSS selector that selects all elements with the class **show-grid** that has a child element whose class *contains* the name **span**.

Comment: actually, it selects the "child element who's class contains the name span" and **not** "all elements with the class show-grid"

Comment: This does not select elements with the class `show-grid`. It selects the descendants (not just children) of those elements having a class name containing "span". It may sound pedantic but it's an important logical distinction.

Answer (score 7):

**The Following:**

```
.show-grid [class*="span"] {
```

**means that all child elements of '.show-grid' with a class that CONTAINS the word 'span' in it will acquire those CSS properties.**

```
<div class="show-grid">
  <div class="span">.span</div>
  <div class="span6">span6</div>
  <div class="attention-span">attention</div>
  <div class="spanish">spanish</div>
  <div class="mariospan">mariospan</div>
  <div class="espanol">espanol</div>

  <div>
    <div class="span">.span</div>
  </div>

  <p class="span">span</p>
  <span class="span">I do GET HIT</span>

  <span>I DO NOT GET HIT since I need a class of 'span'</span>
</div>

<div class="span">I DO NOT GET HIT since I'm outside of .show-grid</span>
```

All of the elements get hit except for the `<span>` by itself.

**In Regards to Bootstrap:**

- `span6` : this was Bootstrap 2's scaffolding technique which divided a section into a horizontal grid, based on parts of 12.  Thus `span6` would have a width of 50%.
- In the current day implementation of Bootstrap (v.3 and v.4), you now use the `.col-*` classes (e.g. `col-sm-6`), which also specifies a media breakpoint to handle responsiveness when the window shrinks below a certain size.  Check [Bootstrap 4.1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) and [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) for more documentation.  I would recommend going with a later Bootstrap  nowadays

Answer (score 4):

It selects all elements where the class name contains the string `"span"` somewhere.  There's also `^=` for the beginning of a string, and `$=` for the end of a string.  Here's [a good reference](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/) for some CSS selectors.

I'm only familiar with the bootstrap classes `spanX` where X is an integer, but if there were other selectors that *ended* in `span`, it would also fall under these rules.

It just helps to apply blanket CSS rules.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm unable to apply background color for class due to dynamic change of class name with numbers

Ex:

**Issue:**

```
body .ForwardRef-root-198 .aura-ag-grid .ag-row:hover, body .ForwardRef-root-198 .ag-details-grid .ag-row:hover {
    background-color: #2196f35c !important;
}
```

**Solution:**

```
body div[class*="ForwardRef-root-"] .aura-ag-grid .ag-row:hover, body div[class*="ForwardRef-root-"] .ag-details-grid .ag-row:hover {
    background-color: #2196f35c !important;
}
```

**Reference:** [link](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)