# what does this mean: css [class*="span"]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm playing around with twitter bootstrap and I noticed this css definition, which I can't seem to override with my own css definitions. What is it and what does it mean:

```
[class*="span"] {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

I tried a google search and nothing came up - maybe it is disallowing search characters or something

Comment: Then search instead for **CSS wildcard selector**

Comment: If you want to find information about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/), you should probably try a search for '[CSS selector site:w3.org](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=CSS+selector+site%3Aw3.org)', and browse the results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What the heck is this: \[class\*="span"\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836151/what-the-heck-is-this-class-span)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

`[class*="span"]` selects elements with a `class` attribute that contains `span`:

```
<div class="in-spanish">Test</div>
               ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an [attribute selector](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) that selects any element that has the class `span`.

Comment: Or the class 'spanned' or 'wingspan'; the `*=` notation simply selects an element based on the presence of a substring, not a white-space delimited occurrence of that substring.