# meaning and role of [class*=] css class selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Asking here since I can't pass a proper search query with that.
Here's a code sample:

```
[class*="button_type"].state_2,
[class*="button_type"]:not(.state_2):hover{
    background-color:#fff;
}
```

Furthermore what would be the use of the `:not` suffix?

I cannot understand why it isn't just:

```
.button_type.state_2,
.button_type:hover { etc..}
```

Comment: Keywords: “Attribute selectors”, “not selector”.

Comment: Take a look here [w3c attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is this CSS selector? \[class\*="span"\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836151/what-is-this-css-selector-class-span)

Comment: `:not` is not a suffix. It's a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[class*="button_type"]` is [CSS class Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) (equivalent to [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) means that will select all elements whose class contains at least one substring "**button_type**".

take a look at this example:

```css
[class*="button_type"] {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="button_type"></div>
<span class="one_button_type"></span>
<article class="button_type_final"></article>
```

Regarding the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) that means it will select everything but that selector which is inside the `:not()`

Take a look at this example:

```css
[class*="button_type"] {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block
}
[class*="button_type"]:not(.state_2) {
  border: black solid
}
```

```html
<div class="button_type state_1"></div>
<span class="one_button_type state_2"></span>
<article class="button_type_final state_3"></article>
```