# What does this CSS statement mean?

Tags: css

I just saw this code.

```
.link--icon [class*='text'] {
    padding-left: 8px;
}
```

What does this line **`.link--icon [class*='text']`** exactly mean?

Comment: It matches any element which has the string `"text"` anywhere in its `class` attribute and has an ancestor with class `link--icon`. So it will match `.link--icon .text` as well as `.link--icon .contextuality`. It won't match `.link--icon .Text` (it's case sensitive).

Answer (score 7):

It is an **attribute wildcard selector**. It looks for a child element under `.link--icon` whose class name contains "text".

Example:

```css
div[class*="test"] {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_test">The first div element.</div>
<div class="second">The second div element.</div>
<div class="test">The third div element.</div>
<p class="test">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Here we have three divs, two divs' classes contain the "test" keyword, so those divs' background is set to "#FFFF00". The middle div doesn't, and the p element doesn't match the div rule, so those are not affected.

Refer to [this w3schools snippet](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_attr_contain) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836151/what-is-this-css-selector-class-span).

Answer (score 0):

`.link--icon [class*='text']` -> Selects every child element of the elements with class `link--icon`, whose `class` attribute value contains the substring `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The `[class*='text']` selector combines descendant and attribute selectors, and matches any element that has the class`"text"` set (for example: `<p class="text">`) and `*` is a wildcard that matches any element.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the specified style will be applied to every element that has any class that contains "text" and is a child of an element with "link--icon" defined at the class attribute.

**.class**: selector for elements by class

**[class*='text']** wild card class selector for elements whose defined class contains the substring 'text'

### Example:

I have the following elements

```
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
<input name="newmilk">
```

If I use the following selector in a css rule: `input[name*='man']`

I will apply the rule to the following elements:

```
<input name="man-news">
<input name="milkman">
<input name="letterman2">
```

[CSS3 attribute selectors](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)

[W3 CSS Selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/)