# Find elements using part of ID

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have, the `div`'s where id looks like `this_div_id_NUMBER`, all `div`'s has the different `NUMBER` part. How I find all `div`'s just using `this_div_id` part of id ?

Comment: Can you post your div, we can't imagine that much.

Comment: @User089247 It's not multiple identical IDs, it's several similar IDs, but they are all unique.

Comment: @NadeemKhan Yes we can, the problem is well enough described. HTML code isn't required for every single thing.

Comment: @Scimonster: Ohk, i got it.Anyways sorry.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can use querySelectorAll to hit partial attribs, including ID:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='this_div_id']")
```

the ^ next to the equal sign indicates "starts with", you can use * instead, but it's prone to false-positives.

you also want to make sure to use quotes (or apos) around the comapare value in attrib selectors for maximum compatibility on querySelectorAll; in jQuery and evergreen browsers it doesn't matter, but in vanilla for old browsers it does matter.

EDIT: late breaking requirement needs a more specific selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='this_div_id']:not([id$='_test_field'])");
```

the not() segment prevents anything ending with "_test_field" from matching.

---

proof of concept / demo: http://pagedemos.com/partialmatch/

Answer (score 14):

### [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

querySelectorAll takes CSS selectors and returns a HTMLNodeList (a kind of array) of all the elements matching that css selector.

The css selector `^` (starts with) can be used for your purpose. **Learn more about it [in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366323/what-does-the-selector-class-span-do).**

For your case, it would be `document.querySelectorAll("[id^='this_div_id']");`

Note that `querySelectorAll` doesn't return a live node list. That means, any changes to the dom would not be updated live in the return value of the function.

Another method would to assign all your elements a specific class and then you can use `getElementsByClassName` (which is much faster than querySelector).

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("divClass");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this selector:

```
[id^="this_div_id_"]
```

**Pure JavaScript: ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll))**

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^="this_div_id_"]')
```

**jQuery: ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/))**

```
$('[id^="this_div_id_"]')
```

**CSS: ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp))**

```
[id^="this_div_id_"] {
    /* do your stuff */
}
```

**Why is this working?**

With the [] in the selector, you can select attributes. Use '=' to match exactly the value or use the '^=' to check if the value starts with. [Read more about this here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Do not include javascript or css for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Using [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

`div[id^="this_div_id"]`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use classes.
But there is one solution that you need (assuming you use jQuery):

```
$("*[id^='this_div_id']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using attribute selector like below:
`$("[id^='this_div_id_']")`