# How do you shorten the CSS when using a H selector with multiple ids?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to take this code and shorten the css:

```
h3#username1, h3#username2, h3#username3 { color:#ff0000;}
```

I tried h3# and h3#* but it didn't work.  How would you shorten the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS attrib->string matching with the `^` like so: `h3[id^="username"]`. You may have to adjust to taste, perhaps using a second directive with the `*` wildcard as well.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/br4hcLus/1/

And more on the thought: [What does the selector [class^="span"] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366323/what-does-the-selector-class-span-do)

Comment: And `h3[id]` if you only care if it has an id, whatever it is.