# select the first selection from dropdownlist using CSSSelector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

below is the select html code and I'm looking for the first option which is `15`

```
<select>
<option value="15" selected="selected">15</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

I have tried this below and I get all the selection `15,25,50,100`

```
div#topPager.gridHeader div.pagerItemContainer select.pagesize option
```

if I use the nth of type like this then I got the first selection.

```
div#topPager.gridHeader div.pagerItemContainer select.pagesize option:nth-of-type(1)
```

is there any other way of doing instead of using the `nth-of-type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More to the point and accurate:

```
#yourSpecificSelectors option[value="15"] {}
```

This is called an attribute selector, in this case it matches the `option` with `value="15"`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: Yes I just realized ;) I never use them..but I don't know why he is doing so...because hardly he can style there

Comment: For that matter, quotes are *not* always optional; if you're looking for a value that starts with a digit, you must either use quotes or escape the digit.

Comment: @BoltClock So you mean when your attr contains numerical val, quotes are compulsory?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I said "starts with".

Comment: @BoltClock: Good call, never knew that: http://jsfiddle.net/RXWrv/ I've always used quotes since I believe jQuery now requires it.

Comment: @WesleyMurch: You have it backwards: [jQuery *used* to require quotes, but not anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987068/do-you-use-quotes-in-jquery-when-searching-for-attribute-values/9987074#9987074) :) Either way, it's always best to use quotes - there is absolutely no reason not to.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah so I see, that's right. You forgot one thing though: IT ADDS BYTES TO MY CSS FILE OMG PERFORMACE WILL SUFFER! ;)

Comment: Yeah... [about that...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743671/is-important-bad-for-performance#comment18885649_13743901)