# Whitespace in CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, whitespace

In the selector a space can indicate a descendant. However, I see spaces can also be ignored.

From my testing, here is what I *think* it means:

- Spaces may be used around `,` and contextual characters (such as `+` and `>`).
- Spaces may *not* be used around pseudo class and element characters (`:` and `::`) as well as attribute selectors (`[…]`).
- Spaces may *not* be used with class and id characters (`.` and `#`).
- Spaces inside a "string" are significant.
- All other spaces are ignored. This includes padding inside an attribute selector.

The question is (a) is this officially correct? and (b) where is this covered?

Comment: The spaces around `,` are not, technically speaking, "whitespace in CSS selectors"; the term "selector" is used to refer to individual selectors, and the comma-delimited list of selectors to the left of the CSS rule is called a "selector list".

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for that comment. The terminology is important when I am trying to teach it to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your conclusions are correct. There are nuances with regard to whitespace in attribute selectors, covered in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930898/what-are-the-rules-around-whitespace-in-attribute-selectors/5930921#5930921).

All the exact rules of where whitespace may or may not appear are covered in the [grammar](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#w3cselgrammar). For the purposes of the grammar, the "contextual characters (such as `+` and `>`)" that you refer to are officially known as combinators. (The term "contextual selector" was first used in CSS1 but hasn't appeared since.)

Remember in addition that any number of contiguous whitespace characters that separate two simple selectors is considered a descendant combinator, which is in fact one reason why whitespace isn't "allowed" around the delimiters for pseudo-elements, pseudo-classes, attribute selectors, class selectors and ID selectors — because it has significance and therefore its presence alters the meaning of the selector.

Comment: Thanks for the information, as well as the link to the grammar and the correct terminology. I always though the use of space as a combinator was unfortunate: not only does it make describing the correct use of spaces more complicated, it is not wholly consistent with other languages where you could say that every space which is not a separator will be ignored.

Comment: @Manngo: Indeed. [The working group agrees.](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes)