# How do I put character &#8226 ::before an element?

Tags: css, html-entities, css-content

I want to put a circle/dot `::before` an element

&#8226

•

nothing I am doing is visible!

```
.line ::before{
    content:'&#8226';
    }
```

and

```
.line ::before{
    content:'•';
    }
```

(I see nothing)

## I can't get this to work even with just text

I know content only accepts text, but I still don't see anything if I do:

```
.line ::before{
    content:'xxx';
    }
```

How do I get css `::before` to show up?

(note: the css rule is in the default style sheet *on page load* so it should be applying to any new element ...)

How do I display this *dot* in `::before`?

Comment: Strongly related, I think: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39091583/1207195

Comment: I found that the space between `.line` and `::before` could ruin things (using Firefox). Remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS `:before` and `:after`'s `content` accepts escaped `\` **Unicode HEX** representation of a character.

**Let's learn how to get to it:**

We could use  `content: "•";` but since we were thought to avoid special characters in favor of  their primitive **Unicode** representation so that we don't get caught in [defining `@charset "utf-8";`](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset) in stylesheets and saving as such. 
**Let's find such HEX value!**

Open up Developer console and write:

```
"•".charCodeAt(0)               // 8226     ( base10 )
```

the above will yield `8226` which is the Decimal Numeric value we generally use in **HTML** like `&#8226;` to get •. *Almost there...*
Now let's  do:

```
"•".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)  // "2022"   ( base16 )
```

```js
console.log(
    "•".charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
)
```

to get a String at **base 16**, so **Hexadecimal**! And you'll get `"2022"`.

#### CSS

```
content: "\2022";
```

#### JavaScript

```
someElement.textContent = "\u2022";
```

#### HTML •

```
&#x2022;
```

:) exactly! You can now abandon decimal base `&#8226;` and always stick to `HEX` value by simply using the right prefix (CSS`\`,  HTML`&#x`, JS`\u`).

---

```css
.line::before{
    content:'\2022';
}
```

```html
<p class="line"> Lorem</p>
```

Comment: That's literally my most favorite answer ever!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like [Entity Converter](https://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html) which will convert your dot to a CSS-exploitable entity: `::before { content: '\2022'; }`. Make sure the font your are using has that character in its character set, or that you use a fallback font that supports that character. Also, make sure you are applying this to a specific element with a selector (`a`, `.someclass`, etc.).