# Why does the following class selector in cheerio doesn't function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, response, cheerio

js code :

```
...

let wr = $('div[class="topstory-content-wrapper last"]');
    console.log(wr.html());

...
```

error: throw new SyntaxError("Malformed attribute selector: " + selector);
                    ^

SyntaxError: Malformed attribute selector: class = topstory-content-wrapper last

Comment: Your selector is malformed. The opening `[` doesn't have a closing `]`. There's spaces all over the place, which makes it unclear.

Comment: You're opening a `[` but not closing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules around whitespace in attribute selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930898/what-are-the-rules-around-whitespace-in-attribute-selectors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to write your selector in the next way:

```
const wr = $('div.topstory-content-wrapper.last');
```

Comment: We can't guarantee that the spaces the OP has aren't needed. Remember  `div .topstory-content-wrapper` is _not the same_ as `div.topstory-content-wrapper.last`

Comment: Yes, agree. Author can try both variants, depends on his needs. 'div' with class, or element with class inside 'div'.